# In BAT file, how do I move a shortcut?

Tags: batch-file

I have the following line in a BAT file, it does not work, how do I make it work?  The shortcut is in the same directory as the BAT file, I have to move it to the desktop.

```
MOVE "MyShortCut.Ink" C:\
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

shortcut files have a `.LNK` extension ("LINK"). You've got `INK` as in "my pen broke and spilled ink all over my shirt".

Answer (score 4):

In Windows, `C:\` is not the the desktop. `C:\Users\[Username]\Desktop` is usually what you're looking for.

There is an environment variable for `C:\Users\[Username]` for the currently logged in user which is `%USERPROFILE%`.

Comment: That's assuming that the OP is on Vista or 7.  If he's still on XP it's c:\Documents and Settings\[Username]\Desktop.  And in that case he should also think about upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

If your running it from another directory, switch to the bat files executing path first;

```
CD %~dp0
MOVE "MyShortCut.Lnk" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
```

Comment: I completely forgot about that environment variable. Nice! +1